# how to assign value from database to label or textbox in asp.net c#

Tags: c#-4.0

i am using the following method to assign value to label or textbox:
First i take dropdownlist then i use databound then i assign dropdownlist value to a label or textbox.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="A" DataTextField="Regisno" DataValueField="Regisno">
    </asp:DropDownList>

 <asp:AccessDataSource ID="A" runat="server" DataFile="~/App_Data/Database.mdb" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [Regisno] FROM [tblsignupv] WHERE ([Email] = ?)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:SessionParameter Name="Email" SessionField="User" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:AccessDataSource>
```

I want to know a method to assign value to label or textbox directly from database using c# code

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your combobox is already filled with data, you can select an item simply by using:

```
DropDownList1.SelectedValue="123";
```

If your values come from a database, then you must use something like :

```
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand();
comm.Connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=[db];user=[user];password=[pwd];");
String sql = @"SELECT [Regisno] FROM [tblsignupv] WHERE ([Email] = '[emailaddress]')";
comm.CommandText = sql;
comm.Connection.Open();
SqlDataReader cursor = comm.ExecuteReader();
while (cursor.Read())
{
     // add your option to the combobox here
     customerID.Items.Add(new ListItem(cursor["text"].ToString(), cursor["value"].ToString()));
}
comm.Connection.Close();
```

of course you need to change the "text" and "value" to the columns of your database.